# What is a feature of an image?

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing

Given an image to train on a CNN what would be considered the features that are the inputs of the model? Would each individual pixel be a feature or would the R,G,B channels be the features?

Lets say I have a 28x28 image with R,G,B channels. Would I say the neural network takes in 28x28 = 784 features, 3 features due to r,g,b , or just 1 feature due to it being just 1 image.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Three channels for a $28\times28$ sounds like $3\times28\times28=2352$ features. The crucial aspect of this, though, is what do you present to the model? Do you show the model each of those $2352$ values for each image?

Comment: typically, a CNN is described as doing its own preprocessing.the convolutional part finds features,and the higer fully connected layers are the classifier on top of the features. the convolutional part can be considered as creating SIFT like features

Comment: @Dave My question is more theoretical. I have been thinking about feature standardization and how it works for images. I have seen various posts talk about different techniques on how to standardize an image and it is somewhat confusing to digest.